# enable_shared_from_this Vs Direct Assignment

Tags: c++, c++11

Why should I use enable_shared_from_this as I can get the same effect via plain assignment also.

```
struct A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
std::shared_ptr<A> getptr() {
    return shared_from_this();
 } 
};


int main () {
// What is the differentce between this code
 std::shared_ptr<A> p1 = make_shared<A>();
 std::shared_ptr<A> p2 = p1->getptr();

// Vs this

 std::shared_ptr<A> p1 = make_shared<A>();
 std::shared_ptr<A> p2 = p1;
}
```

Comment: `void A::member_function() { some_other_function(shared_from_this()); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you can't get the "same" effect", at least not the one you may be thinking of.

There is no difference in the posted code methodologies, precisely because `A` inherits from `std::enable_shared_from_this<A>`. Both p1 and p2 are shared_ptr objects referring to the same concrete object (assuming only one of those sections is compiled for your tests, else you error on id name reuse).

`std::enable_shared_from_this<T>` allows you to acquire a `std::shared_ptr<T>` from some object, formally managed by some preexisting `std::shared_ptr<T>` of type `T` or derivative thereof, in locations where you have no `std::shared_ptr<T>` to the object to otherwise acquire, but need one for one reason or another. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A;

void foo(std::shared_ptr<A> arg)
{
}

struct A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
    void method()
    {
        foo(shared_from_this());
    }
};


int main ()
{
    auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
    a->method();
}
```

In the above example, `foo` requires a `std::shared_ptr<A>` as a parameter. From the body of `A::method()` no such mechanism exists without `std::enable_shared_from_this<A>` as a base. Without the `std::enabled_shared_from_this<T>` base, you would have to provide an alternative mechanism for passing the `a` shared pointer down the call chain until it reached `foo`. In short it would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A;

void foo(std::shared_ptr<A> arg)
{
}

struct A
{
    void method(std::shared_ptr<A> me)
    {
        foo(me);
    }
};


int main ()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
    a->method(a);
}
```

which is obviously dreadful and hideous. Further, there is no guarantee `me` in `method` is actually a `std::shared_ptr<T>` of `this`. Thus the standards committee blessed us with `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thank you so much. I totally spaced that in a copy/paste from a prior rev of that sample. You're the best, sir. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably worth mentioning what `shared_from_this` is 'for'.

The most common use case is to 'keep myself alive' while some asynchronous process is running. A good example of this would be a completion handler, another would be a callback on 'this' when this is controlled by a `shared_ptr`.

for example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::literals;

template<class Handler>
void long_process_with_completion_handler(Handler done)
{
    std::thread([done] {
        std::cout << "long process starts" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2000ms);
        done();
    }).detach();
}


struct controller : std::enable_shared_from_this<controller>
{
    auto get_lock() const {
        return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(_mutex);
    }

    void start() {
        long_process_with_completion_handler([self = shared_from_this()] {
            auto lock = self->get_lock();
            std::cout << "all complete" << std::endl;
        });
    }

    mutable std::mutex _mutex;
};


int main()
{
    std::condition_variable controller_done;
    std::mutex done_mutex;
    bool is_controller_done = 0;

    // make shared controller

    // start its processing
    auto pcontroller = std::shared_ptr<controller>{ new controller,
        [&](auto*p) {
            delete p;
            auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(done_mutex);
            is_controller_done = true;
            std::cout << "controller destroyed" << std::endl;
            lock.unlock();
            controller_done.notify_all();
    }};
    pcontroller->start();

    // destroy the controlling pointer. but our controller is still running...
    pcontroller.reset();

    auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(done_mutex);
    controller_done.wait(lock, [&]{ return is_controller_done;});
    std::cout << "program ends" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The shared-from-this functionality enables you to obtain a `shared_ptr` to a `shared_ptr`-managed object when all you have is a raw pointer or a reference.

Just creating a `shared_ptr` directly from the raw pointer would create a new, unrelated reference counter.

Comment: that i know, in the example above I am not creating the raw pointer. it usage make_shared<>.

Answer (score 1):

The use case of `enable_shared_from_this` and `shared_from_this` is clear, and yet I tend to say that in most use cases it can be dropped in favor of a `static` method that gets a `shared_ptr` and then creates a new `shared_ptr` from it (in a very similar manner to the approach suggested by the OP, but with a static method to support the creation of the new `shared_ptr`).

**The advantage** of the `static` method approach is that you won't fall in the bug of trying to get `shared_from_this` when there is no underlying `shared_ptr` for this instance, resulting with `bad_weak_ptr`.

**The disadvantage** is that the API is implicitly asking the caller to come with a `shared_ptr`, so if the caller has just a raw pointer to an instance he can't use it (the caller may create a `shared_ptr` from the raw pointer and call the method, but how can he tell if the original raw pointer was not managed already by a `shared_ptr`?). On the other hand, if the user has in hand a `unique_ptr` he should be positively sure that turning it to `shared_ptr` in order to call the static method should be fine.

In a way the advantage and disadvantage are two sides of the same coin.

I would prefer in most cases to require the API to work with `shared_ptr` (it already depends on that in a way) rather than allowing working with any kind of a pointer, with the hope that there is a managed `shared_ptr` for it. This goes well with the advice of having APIs that cannot be easily used in a wrong way.

Here is the code presented by @RichardHodges (great example!) using the static method approach instead of using `enable_shared_from_this`:

```
// code based on Richard Hodges example

template<class Handler>
void long_process_with_completion_handler(Handler done) {
    std::thread([done] {
        std::cout << "long process starts" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2000ms);
        done();
    }).detach();
}

// without the need to inherit from std::enable_shared_from_this
struct Controller {
    auto get_lock() const {
        return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(_mutex);
    }
    static void start(std::shared_ptr<Controller>& pcontroller) {
        long_process_with_completion_handler(
        [self = std::shared_ptr<Controller>(pcontroller)] {
            auto lock = self->get_lock();
            std::cout << "all complete" << std::endl;
        });
    }
    mutable std::mutex _mutex;
};

int main() {
    std::condition_variable controller_done;
    std::mutex done_mutex;
    bool is_controller_done = 0;
    // make shared controller and start its processing
    auto pcontroller = std::shared_ptr<Controller>{ new Controller,
        [&](auto*p) {
            delete p;
            auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(done_mutex);
            is_controller_done = true;
            std::cout << "controller destroyed" << std::endl;
            lock.unlock();
            controller_done.notify_all();
    }};
    Controller::start(pcontroller);

    // destroy the controlling pointer. but our controller is still running...
    pcontroller.reset();

    auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(done_mutex);
    controller_done.wait(lock, [&]{ return is_controller_done;});
    std::cout << "program ends" << std::endl;
}
```

Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/281b0ef6d1b31c56