# bad_weak_ptr when shared_from_this() after i already made a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have created a shared_ptr which is giving me the bad_weak_ptr error at runtime error. Does anyone know the reason? What can I do to fix the error?

```
class base:enable_shared_from_this<base> {
public:
    virtual void wtf() { shared_from_this(); };//bad_weak_ptr here
};
class c1 :public base {};
using basep = shared_ptr<base>;
void main() {
    basep bp = make_shared<c1>();//shared_ptr here
    bp->wtf();
}
```

Comment: You need to *publicly* inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this<>`, otherwise `std::make_shared<>` can't tell that it has to set the `weak_ptr<base>`

Comment: @Frank You are right!Thx.

Comment: @Frank Why is the diagnostic? Oops, you can't have one. Another reason I hate this design.

Comment: Why don't you have your own factory method? After all, you must have a way to guarantee that all objects of the types are managed by a `shared_ptr`, right? If you have a factory, why don't you initialize a `weak_ptr` member yourself? That way, no accessibility issue.

Comment: @curiousguy I'm not sure I understand your objection. Of course you have to let the scopes outside of your class be aware of `enable_shared_from_this<>` for it to work. If your objection is that you would have wanted a compile-time error, the only way to get that would be to enforce that ownership of types inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this<>` be only managed by `shared_ptr<>`, which is way worse.

Comment: @Frank My objection is that there is no need for `enable_shared_from_this` if you have a factory where you can initialize a `weak_ptr` yourself. And if you don't have a factory, what guarantees that all your objects are managed by a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: @curiousguy I agree. Here is what I think of that, in another scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38244552/2085626